# Как подставить значение переменной в строку?

Tags: python, glob

Мне нужно передать переменную в модуль glob для поиска динамических файлов:

```
host = 'VirtualMachine1'
Так:
nodes = glob.glob('/home/user/**/*/host.yml', recursive=True)
или так:
nodes = glob.glob('/home/user/**/*/{host}.yml', recursive=True)
print (nodes)
```

не работает.

Comment: Я поправил вашу тему. Теперь можете погуглить на эту тему и найти 100500+ ответов.

Comment: Благодарю. Сам смеюсь со своей формулировки.

Comment: Выделить из проблемы самую суть - это не всегда просто. И сразу решает до 90% проблемы )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вариант можно так (для Python 3.6+):

```
host = 'VirtualMachine1'    
print(f'/home/user/**/*/{host}.yml')
```

Либо используйте метод строки string.format(), где в {} заключаются переменные.

```
host = 'VirtualMachine1'
print('/home/user/**/*/{}.yml'.format(host))
```